# Help wanted: clean up the [untagged] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

I recently found this [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag. It now contains 134 questions on Stack Overflow. 
(If you can't vote to delete, you can focus on the [open questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[untagged]+closed%3A0).)

*(Update: now - 2011-07-12 13:53 UTC - 106 ones are left, of which 53 are non-closed.)*

As one can't create untagged questions (and I doubt anyone puts this tag intentionally on his question), these most likely occur either through migration from other sites (see the [migrated questions tool](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=migrated)), by [expiring seldom-used tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) (e.g. these which are used only once, and created more than 6 months ago), or by burninating tags that are not wanted (often after a request here on meta).

Either way, I found that the list of these questions seems to be a good list of questions which could be worked on:

- quite some are simply off topic ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085309/advice-the-making-of-a-software-product)), and should be closed and/or migrated (but possible tagged first to get them off the list).
- others are on-topic, but need some editing, and/or [only proper tags](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5973505/revisions).

This is not so much a question, but more a call for volunteers: If you have some superfluous time, go through this list and tag/flag/close-vote these questions. (Or answer them, after tagging.)

Of course, **proper tags** here means normally tags which are already used for other questions, else we have the same problem again after some months.

**UPDATE** as of today (2nd October) there are still 37 [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) questions. I've [ChrisF] been through them and they're all pretty much off topic so I've cast votes as appropriate. I've also cast delete votes on the ones that are already closed.

**Update** as of now (UTC 2011-10-03 11:22) there are zero [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) questions. I've [AakashM] been through them and votes close / delete as possible, and retagged them all (even the closed ones, because hey, I'm a programmer, and there are either zero or not-zero such questions in the system :)

Comment: Well, I'm out of close votes for the day now!

Comment: Yeh, I cleaned up all the ones on [boardgames](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) and you're right they all needed more cleanup.

Comment: Questions are tagged with [tag:untagged] also when they used a tag that was just used in a single question, and that has been automatically deleted.

Comment: Cleaning those up gives you a lot of flag opportunities.

Comment: Ah, another [quest](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97958/help-me-defeat-the-barbarians-in-the-regex-tag). I retagged a handful that were on-topic; I'd be happy to see the rest closed and deleted.

Comment: @Lance: Agreed. Are there any other tags out there begging for cleanup like this one?

Comment: @Andrew, there's always plenty of cleanup to be done, but the `untagged` one is the most obvious.  You already know every question with that tag needs cleaning up before you even go into it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, if the sole question has been deleted, then how would there be any questions with that tag?  but they do run a sole-tag deletion script, and that will eliminate the tag but leave the question.

Comment: @Lance Roberts The "and that has been automatically deleted" part is referred to the tag. Tags used from a single question are automatically deleted. When the tag is automatically deleted, if the question was tagged only with that tag, the question will be retagged with [tag:untagged].

Comment: For those lazy like me, here's a query that hides the already closed questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buntagged%5D+closed%3A0

Comment: Could this be a black-listed tag please?

Comment: @MTib - I'm assuming it's an automatically-applied tag when a question's other tags are mass-deleted.

Comment: @Andrew There's a lot of questions tagged windows and forms which should be winforms.  The forms tag says it's for web-based forms, which aren't really the same thing as winforms forms.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: This was what I meant by "expiring seldomly-used tags".

Comment: I apologize; I didn't understand that you were already referring to that.

Comment: No problem, your explanation might have helped someone else. I'll add some comment regarding this.

Comment: 32 close votes later, I've gone through the list.

Comment: 5 delete votes later, I'll come back in 9 hours to get more work done.

Comment: Down to 22 questions. Need more close and delete votes.

Answer (score 2):

I went through and voted to close until I ran out of votes.  It looks like programmers.stackexchange is about to get an influx of old untagged questions.  A moderator should go in and delete alot of those questions too.  I flagged a few myself.

Comment: Reminder to everyone: [**Don't migrate crap**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89169/please-just-close-garbage-questions-instead-of-moving-them-to-programmers-se/89171#89171), even if it would theoretically be on-topic. When in doubt, just close as off-topic without migrating.

Comment: You should not migrate bad questions or extremely old questions to other sites. Just vote to close as "off topic". That's what it's there for. You can close a question as off-topic without migrating it. You're just creating extra work for moderators to delete the questions you've improperly migrated, and they don't need any extra work.

Comment: +1, thanks for doing something! You've put time and energy into something to help people...(but also reminder of moving crap)...

Comment: @Cody Gray ok next time i wont help

Comment: @OffBySome As a Stack Overflow user I appreciate you going through the `untagged` questions, but as a Programmers moderator I'd like to second what bemace and Cody have said. Please don't migrate questions that don't deserve to stay open. Everybody's happy that way. :)