# I need help with mass editing, where can I turn to?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering, where can we turn to if we set out on a holy crusade and face hundreds or even thousands of edits<sup>1</sup> and can't just do it alone?

Should we open up a question here, with appropriate links and information? Should we post our cry for help in the chat?

<sup>1</sup>: *Not retagging* ([I know that's a bad thing](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/837/many-hours-of-work-on-tags-reverted-without-discussion-moderator-abusing-their)), in this case it is replacing and inlining shortened URLs.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52816/etiquette-for-enormous-hand-sorted-retagging-jobs

Comment: What kind of hypothetical edits are you talking about anyway?  I can only think of a few instances where it'd be appropriate and in most of those cases it's not urgent enough to require a crusade, just a mention to "hey fix this if you happen to edit an existing post with this in it".

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo: See my footnote, I wanted to remove shortened URLs (to also get rid of remaining LMGTFY links), but that's close to 750 posts to edit...which is a little too much for myself.

Comment: If you keep flagging the LMGTFY links I will "edit" those for you.  ;)

Comment: Inlining shortened URLs seems like something that could be done a lot easier by the dev team using a script. But there are [other quests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97958/help-me-defeat-the-barbarians-in-the-regex-tag) you can take up if you're feeling edity

Comment: [You need a posse](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/posse).

Comment: @bemace: I'm not sure if the devs *want* to do it completely automatic. The answer needs to be checked, edited and maybe salvaged. It's basically manual cleanup. But yes, if they can and want to do it, I'm all in for it.

Comment: @Anna Lear: Yes! \*dark.voice\* I need Minions! \*cough.cough\* Where did that come from? Anyway, now back to my question: Is Meta the right place for that, should I post it in the chat or write to the team?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think meta is a fine place for such a call to arms, as it were. Make a post outlining your plan and ask for volunteers. Advertising the post in chat might not be a bad idea either.

Then you'll either get your [posse](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/posse) or someone will pipe in with arguments against and/or a better way to do things. Either way it's a win.