# Title-Search only highlights keyword in body

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Jason Plank pointed towards [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title:question&submit=search) in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101923/ive-found-a-particular-set-of-questions-with-bad-titles), the highlighting behavior seems odd to me...

(*Compare it with the [results without modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=question&submit=search)*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the next build we'll highlight titles correctly, additionally *only* terms seeked in the title will be highlighted.  For example: `body:apples title:oranges` would *only* highlight `oranges` in the title.  The same applies for quotes strings, etc.

It will now do a regex pull of title terms from the query lucene actually runs...but note: the same rules don't apply to the body yet, as it's highlighted, or rather summarized in a completely different way.