# Should I write the error message as title of my question?

Tags: discussion, title

Most of the time that people search in the internet, they look for an error message, so is expected that to help SEO we should add the error message in the title. Is a good behavior?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102027/how-should-questions-about-compiler-errors-be-titled

Comment: Who are you calling "most people"?

Comment: @random you, me, and people like us.

Comment: Then you're wrong because most of the searches have been about SpongeBob and what Jonathan Taylor Thomas is doing these days

Comment: @random really? I was looking for GoT as late, not so much Bob or Taylor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that you are asking about should go in the title.  If you're asking how to resolve an error message, the error message should go in the title.

There's nothing more frustrating than getting a google match on a Stack Exchange question for "How do I foo the bar?" only to find that the question isn't about how to foo the bar at all, but how to fix some obscure error message.

Comment: Should be full error message? And exactly, I hate those moments.

Comment: The relevant part of the error message.  Java exceptions include a stack dump; you're not going to get all that to fit into a title.

Comment: I mean things like "can't import module 'something'" and those kind of short but unique errors. OK, now that I read it again, it's what I was looking for.

Comment: "Can't import module 'something' when trying to foo the bar."