# Add search to the review section

Tags: feature-request, search, review

As [we've seen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83075/what-are-the-best-ways-to-find-answers-that-should-be-flagged), search can be a powerful tool for finding posts in need of flags or edits. Currently, to review using a search query you have to click through to every post from the search results before you can read and flag/edit it.

I propose that there should be a page under [/review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/), where you can have search results come up in "review" format, thus making the process less tedious.

Here's a quick mockup:
[image: a quick mockup]

Another idea is to allow combining search with the existing heuristics, although I suspect the implementation of this might be tricky.

Comment: It would be greate if *somehow*, I could say I only wish to see matching posts that have been reviewed by less then "n" people.   Or to show me the posts first that have been reviewed by the least number of people.  Also don't show me any posts that already have a un-processed flag on them.

Answer (score 4):

How about we just get an advanced search operator like **isreview:1**?

Though I guess you just want the Review format for any search results, but I think this is dangerous since the posts should be looked at more carefully before flagging them.  *I never use the flag functionality from the review screen*, but alway go into the post to look at the whole thing.  There's too much not shown on that front page, like links and images, that tell a larger story.  Not to mention, that the question the answer is for might show the answer to be a good one in context.

Comment: Adding a new search operator would probably be the quick fix solution, but it might be somewhat less discoverable than having it together with the other review tools. Also note that the review format does have a "show full post" link which expands it inline. You still don't get the context of the question, but this concern applies to all of the review section, and many bad answers can be identified as such without the extra context.

Comment: @hammar, there have been many answers I thought might be bad, until I clicked into the full context.  I hadn't used the `full answer` link before, it is nice.

Comment: Also, while you have a point about checking the context before flagging, using the "full post" link you can at least quickly filter out the posts that you can tell are _ok_ without context.

Comment: @hammer, yep, good point.