# Can closed:[0-1] apply to the parent question when is:answer is specified via search?

Tags: feature-request, search

Some users on Stack Overflow have been spending a bit of time [helping us find duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103632/lets-clean-up-the-this-is-a-duplicate-answers/103638#103638) that really need to be closed. This is working out very well, I'm hoping we can cut out some noise for them when they execute these types of searches.

Suppose we have the query:

[`is:answer isaccepted:1 body:"duplicate" url:"*stackoverflow.com/*"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3A1+body%3A%22duplicate%22+url%3A%22%2Astackoverflow.com%2F%2A%22)

And we want to refine it so that we only see open questions. Adding `closed:0` to that *seems* like it should filter out questions that have already been closed, but in reality it doesn't because *answers* can't be closed.

This seems easy to fix if `closed:[0-1]` applies to the *parent* question when `is:answer` is toggled.

Answer (score 1):

I have some suggestions on how to tackle this on the technical level.  If I were to write a userscript for this, I would look for URL's in the list that contained '#' in them. Answers have extra path variables in the URL, so looking for URLs that don't contain a '#' and then removing them would essentially remove any questions from the list of results.

**Example Answer:**

> freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/773/is-it-possible-to-get-freelancing-gigs-in-project-management-or-recruiting-field/786**#786**  <--- Has hash and number in the final path variable

**Example Question:**

> freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/773/is-it-possible-to-get-freelancing-gigs-in-project-management-or-recruiting-field/   <-- No hash or number in the final path variable

This is just a start. I checked the Stack Exchange API to see if it were possible to obtain a collection of answers with post notices. Unfortunately, this is not included.  So another solution to this problem is to add this filter to the /answers API call.

If a Stack Exchange developer were to tackle this, he or she could theoretically filter the results on the server by removing results with no hash. While easier to implement, I'm not sure what performance impacts this could have on the system, so this is just a proposed idea to help get this done. Hope this helps.