# Semantic change for closed:1 when is:answer?

Tags: discussion, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Can closed:[0-1] apply to the parent question when is:answer is specified via search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104585/can-closed0-1-apply-to-the-parent-question-when-isanswer-is-specified-via-sea)

### Background:

Yesterday (and tonight) I was looking for questions to help [clean up the "this is a duplicate" answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103632/152009).  I found that the search:

[`is:answer isaccepted:1 body:"duplicate" url:"*stackoverflow.com/*"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3A1+body%3A%22duplicate%22+url%3A%22%2Astackoverflow.com%2F%2A%22)

was very helpful; **however**, it would be a huge benefit if we could add:

`closed:0`

to the above search.  In other words, return only *open questions* with accepted answers which contain "duplicate".

I was [quite surpised](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/708587#708587) when this didn't work, but as [Sathya](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/133693/sathya) explains, **answers cannot be closed**.

### My Question:

Couldn't the `closed:1` or `closed:0` **always** apply to *the question*?

If this is the intended behavior, then the following search:

`is:answer isaccepted:1 body:"duplicate" url:"*stackoverflow.com/*" closed:0`

shouldn't return zero results.  This would provide a very nice reduction in noise when editing / flagging.

Comment: If you hex encode the `*`s in the url it will work fine: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3A1+body%3A%22duplicate%22+url%3A%22%2Astackoverflow.com%2F%2A%22

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks so much!  Question updated.

Comment: Crap.  Tim & I were chatting about proposing this.  I didn't realize he did.  Feel free to close mine.

Comment: I asked a few other mods if there was currently a way to do this that perhaps we didn't know about, then noticed you hadn't proposed it yet so I went ahead. I keep a short list of stuff to follow up on, and this was on it. Sorry for forgetting to ping you. BTW, I posted that feature request we were kicking around.

Comment: No worries.  Thanks so much!  I'd really appreciate this feature.