# Advanced search for closed answers returns all closed questions

Tags: bug, answers, search, closed-questions

Searching for closed answers should returns zero items due to only questions can be closed. But [result is not empty and contains closed questions only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa%20closed%3A1):

> [image: closed answers]

Comment: Downvoter, do you think search result is relevant to request?

Comment: My guess is that is:a searches for answers, while closed:1 searches for questions. This leads to a contradiction, and the search engine produces all threads because it doesn't know what else to do.

Comment: FWIW this isn't limited to Meta.SE.

Comment: @DonielF most questions on MSE related to whole SE network. Questions related only to this very site should be tagged [tag:meta].

Comment: @DonielF this seems most likely.

Comment: After some similar experiences, I use the [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) for similar digging. You have access to much more data as in the site search and it does exactly what you ask. (Furthermore, you have access to better site stats as the 25k+ users, but it is a different story).

Comment: @MartijnPieters "`is:a closed:yes` search now produces 0 results"... where?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ: nowhere, it turns out. The search engine blipped instead.

Comment: Some related posts: [is:answer flag in advanced search should only return answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201973) and [Can closed:\[0-1\] apply to the parent question when is:answer is specified via search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104585)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug, or if anything, just a display bug, i.e. the "answers only" should indeed be removed as that option is simply ignored.

The advanced search operators got priorities behind the scenes, the `closed:1` operator happens to be on higher priority than `is:a` so that's what being used.

Starting to check in advance for such "conflicts" is very complicated as there are great many combinations, and it's really not worth the efforts in my opinion.

Comment: Then why does it display all questions and not just closed ones?

Comment: @DonielF it's not all questions. Meta.SE has more than 80,000 questions, the result produces 30-something thousand.

Comment: @M.A.R. Okay, but it still produces open ones.

Comment: @DonielF both `is:a closed:yes` and `closed:yes is:a` produce 22,382 results for me. Only `closed:yes` produces 22,382 results as well. Anyway, it doesn't matter since a trivial bug from a behavior you don't need or should be producing isn't fix-worthy.

Comment: @DonielF no repro, it's showing only closed questions to me. Can you post screenshot where you see open question in the search results?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, I can't seem to. It was definitely showing all questions before, but I can't reproduce it now, either.