# Etiquette for flagging a high rep user's old answer as Not an Answer

Tags: discussion, flags

I've been working through the flag queue recently and noticed a decent number of *Not an Answer* flags on answers given a few years ago by users who now have high reputation (>3k let's say). These are [obvious non-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219843/count-vs-countid-in-sql-server-2005/2227143#2227143) (not specifically picking on this one), but it still feels like cheap flag weight to add my flag onto the existing one. I'd rather not lump punitive measures against a productive member for really old answers.

I would like them cleaned up, but in a manner that is respectful of their earned reputation. Would it be better to add a comment to their non-answer suggesting it be self deleted?

Comment: Do flag them, they may even date back to before the system had comments!

Comment: During [my recent crusade against non-answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103632/lets-clean-up-the-this-is-a-duplicate-answers), I ended up flagging posts by many high-rep users, including Jeff and several moderators. It's not a big deal. They were all accepted and I even got a Marshal badge out of it.

Comment: @hammar: I'd flagged a good lot of them before it dawned on me there may be system checks in place which trigger on multiple *Not An Answer*. If this is not the case, I'll go back to my regularly scheduled flagging.

Comment: Why are you treating high reputation users with bad answers differently than low reputation users with bad answers? An answer that is bad is an answer that is bad

Comment: @ClaraOnager: correct. My concern was triggering a post ban for answers from 2+ years ago.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suck up the cheap flag weight while you can, if you are flagging correctly then it makes SO a better place while you do it.

High rep users know how SO works, and know that old posts can accumulate both upvotes and downvotes. Those same high rep users may well have been low rep users when they posted that answer, and could well be embarrassed by it if they remembered it, so do them a favor and help get rid of it.

Comment: I'm running with this under the assumption it won't cause them to get hit by the quality filter.

Answer (score 10):

Have you seen this hilarious gallery of dogs who look like their owners?

[image]

Comment: Seriously, this is of course meant to say that IMO flag away on obvious non-answers, no matter how high the user's reputation is. :)

Comment: If they have enough flagged/closed will it disconfabulate their postitude? Don't want someone quality filter banned for posts 2 years ago.

Comment: @six good point, hadn't thought of that! But have enough trust in SO's algorithms to assume a few flagged non-answers will not cause anybody trouble who has been a good contributor for some time.

Comment: Awesome pic. However, I don't really feel obligated to upvote.

Comment: Yea I'm jaded too Chicihary. Sorry I botched the sp there. Have an UV

Comment: _Flagged as not an answer._

Comment: @Chichiray you're just jealous because you don't look much like your owner. You're way too green!

Comment: Twisters are also green!

Comment: Must...resist...urge...to...upvote...\*bites.his.fingers\*

Comment: @Chichi That is hard to deny.

Comment: Pfft... Less than 30K?  n00b.  Flagged.

Comment: How do we know that those dogs actually belong to those owners, and weren't just random dogs plucked from obscurity because they resembled a human? You just can't believe *anything* you read on teh interwebs these days.

Comment: hah..there's actually a sense of humor on meta