# Which words in titles are blacklisted on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, quality-filter, blocklist

Is there a complete list of blacklisted words for titles?

I think there's:

- problem
- error
- issue

But I'd like to be sure.

Comment: So, network-wide or just Stack Overflow? Because I think the ones you listed are SO only. Also, [closed] and [migrated] are blocked, too.

Comment: "Error" and "issue" are not blocked (yet – let's keep it that way).

Comment: @lunboks SO (or trilogy)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### All Sites

- `[duplicate]`
- `[closed]`
- `[migrated]`
- `[tag]` at the beginning of the title (`tag` can be (almost) any string)

#### Trilogy Sites (SO, SE, SF)

- `problem`
- `help` (only at the beginning of the title, or if followed by  `with`; [ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109011/too-many-restrictions-in-titles/109040#109040))
- `question` (confirmed on SO at least)

---

Additionally,

- Pseudo-tags are [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70498/159624).
- Exclamation marks at the end of titles are [automatically converted to question marks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102807/159624)

Comment: Feel free to expand – I don't want to go fill every site with test questions :P

Comment: It seems you can test this without actually posting a question: just typing in the title and changing input focus is enough to trigger an AJAX validation check.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, that's possible ever since they revamped the error messages. Before you'd have had to submit the question in order to test this.

Comment: FWIW, currently, it seems that some of these words are only blacklisted in _short_ titles. For example, the title "asdfghjkl asdfghjkl problem asdfghjkl" currently triggers the blacklist on SO, but adding one more "asdfghjkl" at the end allows it to pass. (I seem to recall seeing this confirmed as a deliberate feature by Shog or someone else at SE, but I didn't manage to Google it up right now.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen regarding the short title, the filter is only applied if the title is [shorter than 40 characters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373388/2821954).