# Please block questions with "help!" and variants

Tags: feature-request, question-quality, quality-filter

I've seen a [number of questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=help%21) ([1](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/640121/1),[2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574983/booting-ubuntu-please-help?s=12%7C0.9155),[3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176672/installation-help),[4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611831/no-password-stuck-help?s=16%7C0.9120),[5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283526/installing-proxychains-help-needed?s=19%7C0.9113)) with "help!" in the title - especially on Ask Ubuntu. I don't know if it is a network wide occurrence.

Please could all questions with "help" and variants - especially when it is in the title - be blocked?

Comment: The existing Problem block is stupid, harmful, and very annoying. Let's not compound the error.

Comment: I can see your point so kind of feel bad for not agreeing with it... if you want to delete let me know and I'll remove my answer so you can do it.

Comment: _cough_ ["probelm"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=probelm) _cough_ ["hlep"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hlep) _cough_

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've actually only lost 1 rep for it :P It's fine, there's no need to remove it - someone else will come along and ask again. :-) Thanks though.

Comment: However, in a site that deals with homework questions, like the one I'm an active user in (chem.SE), *help* in titles is **always** redundant. Even if the question is valid, with a *help* in its title, it suffers from a bad title. Such a feature wouldn't be bad there.

Answer (score 19):

Believe it or not, but the word "help" can be used as part of valid programming question title. Some examples I found by quick search:

1. [How does password salt help against a rainbow table attack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420843/how-does-password-salt-help-against-a-rainbow-table-attack)
2. [Mercurial: abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477781/mercurial-abort-no-username-supplied-see-hg-help-config)
3. [Opening Vim help in a vertical split window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630884/opening-vim-help-in-a-vertical-split-window)

And believe me, blocking "help!" will just make the user find creative ways to bypass it:

> halp, heelp, help!!, haalp, hellp, ...

All in all: pointless. Let it go through and let users edit it out if bothered by it.

Comment: True, but this isn't how SO filter works: it blocks help [at the beginning of the title, or if followed by  with](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110890/259867). And no, I don't believe that it produces a substantial number of halp or heelp.

Comment: It becomes a problem when you have 30% of the titles on your site like that. 60k questions title for little less than 200k questions. And I tell you, 99.999999999999999999% it isn't descriptive.