# Am I going overboard with these question title edits that are part of a tag clean-up?

Tags: discussion, questions, title, clean-up

[This link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99519/need-suggestions-about-cleaning-up-a-tag-and-revisiting-very-old-questions) describes my goal and I am currently working on it (*2.06%* done so far). Below given are the questions that I have rephrased in the best of interests that I think would serve the community better. I would like to know if I am going overboard with this whole rephrasing questions thing.

- Did I do something that I shouldn't have done? If so, please comment where I went wrong so I can correct my mistakes.

I have given the initial question against row `From` and the question that it has been rephrased to against `To` and the reason why I did rephrased them against the row `Reason`. I appreciate your inputs. Complete status of what I am doing can be found [here](https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApER3lN2ToXXdHBIZ3RGNnRwLWdNUTc0ZnVFTTBvOXc&hl=en_US).

[image: Questions_From_To_Reason]

Comment: Excellent work (at least I think so).  If a question is tagged SSIS already, it may be redundant to put that in the title.  The only reason you would need it would be if SSIS were peripherally related to the topic in an unusual way.

Comment: By volume, this isn't "going overboard." However -- and this is quite subjective -- [some people would say](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99185/would-the-stack-exchange-network-be-better-if-titles-contained-complete-grammati) that your improved titles could stand to be improved further.

Comment: @Popular True.  I think it's a great effort, in any case.

Comment: I think all these edits are fine; though I would go a step further and make the titles into questions themselves. +1

Comment: Related: *[Would the Stack Exchange network be better if titles contained complete, grammatical questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99185)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably already know this, but I'll just mentioned the question titles you changed where I believe you had the greatest impact.  This might allow you to prioritize or reduce the amount of work you have to do.  The remaining edits I haven't mentioned I would consider "optional" edits.

> ### 4, 11, 13

These are the "non-titles," the ones that desperately need editing because they don't mean anything.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, I agree. Anyway, I will be going through every question under [tag:ssis]. I would like to make them look consistent. My thoughts were to present the questions in the best possible manner even for non-SO users who might come across this in search engine results. I just pointed out only the questions but I am also going through every answer to make sure they look perfect. I like the community and I would like to make it better for others too. One tag at a time!